# Error configuring using Windows Service Bus (1.1) Configuration Wizard

Tags: servicebus

I am trying to configure Windows Service Bus (1.1) using Service Bus Configuration Wizard. I am getting below error when I try to configure it. Can anybody tell me what is the problem.

**[Error] [5/9/2014 9:32:40 AM]: System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Starting service Service Bus Gateway on machine USHP2-10-056A failed: Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed. ---> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.Common.Exceptions.OperationFailedException: Starting service Service Bus Gateway on machine USHP2-10-056A failed: Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed. ---> System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException: Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed.**

Please see below for Configuration Information of Service Bus

Management Database SQL Instance    USHP2-10-056A\SQLSERVER2012SP1

Enable SSL connection with SQL Server instance  False

Authentication  Windows Authentication

Management Database Name    SbManagementDB

Gateway Database SQL Instance   USHP2-10-056A\SQLSERVER2012SP1

Enable SSL connection with SQL Server instance  False

Authentication  Windows Authentication

Gateway Database Name   SbGatewayDatabase

Message Container SQL Instance  USHP2-10-056A\SQLSERVER2012SP1

Enable SSL connection with SQL Server instance  False

Authentication  Windows Authentication

Message Container Database Name SBMessageContainer01

RunAs Account   gopalac-c@HERBALIFECORP

RunAs Password  ***********

Certificate Generation Key  *********** (Gopala123)

Farm Certificate    Auto-generated

Encryption Certificate  Auto-generated

HTTPS Port  9355

TCP Port    9354

Message Broker Port 9356

Resource Provider HTTPS Port    9359

Amqp Port   5672

Amqps Port  5671

Internal Communication Port Range   9000 - 9004

Enable firewall rules on this computer  True

Administrators Group    BUILTIN\Administrators

Registering container databases SBMessageContainer01 SBMessageContainer02 
SBMessageContainer03

Creating Namespace  ServiceBusDefaultNamespace

Management Portal Admin User    adminUser

Management Portal Tenant User   tenantUser

Comment: You can check the event viewer for any additional clues on what could be wrong. You can find the service bus logs under Applications and Services Logs and then expand the Microsoft-ServiceBus node.

Answer (score 1):

Look in \Windows\System32\drivers\etc and edit the hosts file - In my case I noticed that I had localhost defined more than once. Even though they were all set to 127.0.0.1 it still seems to have confused the Service Bus config.

I removed the duplicates and then it worked.

Comment: I moved from one client to another before I got Peter's above reply. if anyone had same problem and solved by following Peter's suggestion let me know I will mark it as answer..

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1 and that is not working, I did not initially have anything mapped to localhost it said that it added that automatically

Comment: NPehrsson... the steps didnot work for you and your problem ( same problem) still exists ?.. if you solved your problem can you please kindly let us know how u solved it...

Comment: I didn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I lost 2 days on this.

My issue.

I had previously (months before) installed and was running RabbitMQ.

This guy gave me the hint:

http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/installing-windows-service-bus

> *Make sure you uninstall all previous versions of the Windows App Fabric on your development machine. **Additionally, disable any
>   windows service that utilizes the AMQP protocol (RabbitMQ). If you do
>   not disable RabbitMQ then the Service Bus will not be able to start
>   up.** Finally, make sure you have SQL Server Express 2012 installed.
>   In regards to SQL Server, make sure to enable TCP/IP protocol; this
>   can be done using the SQL Server Configuration Manager tool.*

Once I stopped all RabbitMQ service, I was able to complete the installation.

Sidenote : I used a domain-account.  I was connected to my domain-network while doing the install.  I did not try with a local-account after I got my issue resolved.

========================================================

Other links I found along the way (besides this one).

http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2012/09/18/servicebus-message-broker-service-is-starting-and-starting.aspx

https://github.com/matthewcanty/Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage.FAKE.dll

http://curtisbadke.ca/blog/2015/10/18/fun-with-installing-service-bus-for-windows/

> *Things you’ll need to be aware of for local Service Bus installation:
>       If you are in a workgroup you must use local users, if you are in a domain you must use domain users. If you are on Windows 10 with an
>   AAD user your machine is probably in a workgroup. reference
>       If you have VS 2015, you need to install a fake Microsoft.Cloud.Common.AzureStorage assembly.
>       You must use Nuget package WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 2.1.4.0 or older.
>       You must address your Service Bus connections using your full machine name not a short name or something like localhost
>       Hopefully this saves someone hours of frustration*

Comment: moved from one client to another before I got granadaCoder's above reply. if anyone had same problem and solved by following granadaCoder's suggestion let me know I will mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following procedure:

**before install**

(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/688ada3c-bb95-488d-9ad0-aec297438e1c/problem-starting-message-broker-during-service-broker-configuration?forum=servbus)

- Open configuration Wizard and select "Leave Farm"
- Delete all the Service Bus related databases in SQL server
- Uninstall Service Bus 1.0 and Windows Fabric
- Remove the folder 'C:\ProgramData\Windows Fabric' if it exists
- Remove the folders 'C:\Program Files\Service Bus' and 'C:\Program Files\Windows Fabric' if it exists

**Reinstall the product:**

- Run "Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConfigWizard.exe" as admin (right-click 'run as admin')
- Choose 'with custom settings'
- Set the 'Internal communication port range' to any unused port (not the default 9000, which is often used)