# Is there a redistributable .NET service bus?

Tags: .net, messaging, esb, servicebus

We make software that customers install themselves on their own servers. We have thousands of customers. I'd like to introduce a service bus into our application.

We need to keep the costs down and have the least possible number of dependencies/prerequisites to simplify our install.

Is there a service bus that is:

- Redistributable
- Cheap - ideally free, or at least isn't priced per install
- Built with .NET
- Doesn't require MSMQ to be installed

Is something like this available or are we stuck building one ourselves?

Comment: A service bus is a key infrastructure service, similar to a database or a queue service. It's not something you can copy and configure with a few clicks. You have to thing about reliability and availability to say the least

Comment: Regarding Azure SB, I can recommend it too. It's affordable and with Azure SDK development is easy. If you put little effort on it, you get good message logging, too. And while at it I bet you come up with other uses for Azure (push notifications for example).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - well, we redistribute SQL Server Express, which is a database, and it can be copied and configured with a few clicks.

Comment: @boris This may be adequate for very small deployments where availability and performance are not an issue. Even with SQL Express though you *do* need to put the transaction log on a different disk than the data files, you *do* need to set up a proper backup and *restore* procedure, you *do* need to make sure you *can* restore the database. Not to mention mirroring or clustering. Just because you automated SQL Server Express setup with an answer file doesn't mean you have configured it properly for production. Consider moving to a managed service like Azure for both SQL and Service bus.

Comment: I've done a lot of research on service busses and found the term to mean a variety of different things to different people/businesses/companies. You may want to be more specific about what your definition of a service bus is (or help us understand what you're trying to accomplish with it). For example, Broker-style service busses like Biztalk are much different that de-centralized service busess like mass transit and nservicebus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Server equivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282144.aspx) available for Windows Azure Service Bus - which offers almost all messaging capabilities of Windows Azure Service Bus and is FREE.

- This is a Standalone product with very few dependencies (Sql Server 2012 being one of them though)
- To install this - first you will need to install [WEB Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) (something like wget for linux) 
  and then Search for 'bus' for product list - and select "Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus Server 1.1"

HTH,
Sree

Comment: Awesome! How did i not know about this...

Comment: Warning : Be prepared for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570681/error-configuring-using-windows-service-bus-1-1-configuration-wizard

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of is using [Azure service bus](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/).
The price is [very low](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/service-bus/) and you don't need to worry about setting up the environment on every client.

A possible problem is that you need internet access. Also if you handle huge amounts of messages the network latency can slow the application.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't have messages leak out outside the customer's private network so a cloud-based service like Azure SB won't work. Latency, as you mentioned, is also an issue.

Comment: Then move the entire application on Azsure and set up a VPN. It will be more secure, reliable and available than having the customer manage security, backups, restores etc. SQL Azure provides automatic failover while SQL Server Express provides no way to failover short of manually restoring the database on another machine and switching all clients to it